# How do I access a dictionary inside a list inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a data that looks like this
`dict1 = [[{'num1':1, 'num2':2, 'num3':3}], [{'num1':4,'num2':5, 'num3':6}]]`

How do I go inside the list where it contains the dictionary to select a specific key to display.
I seem to be getting a lot if list index out of range error.

Here's my current code:

```
for items in dict1:
   for index in range(len(dict1)):
       print(items[index]['num1'])
```

Comment: You mean `len(items)`, but don't do that. Just do `for items in dict1: for item in items: print(item['num1'])`

Comment: Better yet, just get rid of those single-element dicts, you can flatten just by: `data = [x for xs in data for x in xs]`

Comment: yeah! that seems to fix the problem for me. i got all the values of a specific key in all my dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather obvious that your `dict1` is not a single-depth list, it's a list of list, so iterate it this way:

```py
dict1 = [[{'num1':1, 'num2':2, 'num3':3}], [{'num1':4,'num2':5, 'num3':6}]]

for t in dict1:
    obj = t[0]

    for key in obj:
        print(key,obj[key])
```